# Docker on visionfive2 risc-v

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, docker

Docker on visionfive2 risc-v

```
user@starfive:~$ sudo dockerd

WARN[2024-03-02T13:08:27.753708638Z] Unable to find memory controller             
WARN[2024-03-02T13:08:27.753772888Z] Unable to find io controller                 
WARN[2024-03-02T13:08:27.753885889Z] Unable to find cpuset controller             
WARN[2024-03-02T13:08:27.753972639Z] Unable to find pids controller               
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.755205397Z] Loading containers: start.                   
WARN[2024-03-02T13:08:27.763888949Z] Running modprobe bridge br_netfilter failed with message: modprobe: WARNING: Module bridge not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive
modprobe: WARNING: Module br_netfilter not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-starfive
, error: exit status 1 
WARN[2024-03-02T13:08:27.921853397Z] Could not load necessary modules for IPSEC rules: protocol not supported 
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.943487527Z] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.970871192Z] [core] Channel Connectivity change to SHUTDOWN  module=grpc
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.971098693Z] [core] Subchannel Connectivity change to SHUTDOWN  module=grpc
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.971636946Z] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.972497202Z] stopping event stream following graceful shutdown  error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.972850954Z] stopping healthcheck following graceful shutdown  module=libcontainerd
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.973038955Z] [core] Channel Connectivity change to SHUTDOWN  module=grpc
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.973209706Z] [core] Subchannel Connectivity change to SHUTDOWN  module=grpc
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.973820710Z] [core] Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.974033461Z] [core] Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2024-03-02T13:08:27.974120461Z] [core] Subchannel picks a new address "unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.sock" to connect  module=grpc
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: package not installed
```

things to rebuild linux kernel but...

which option to activate when run "make menuconfig"? need "bridge" and "br_netfilter"

thank you for our time

Comment: Have you tried enabling `CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER` in the kernel build configuration?

Comment: Even more important your kernel lacks cgroups. You can try this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/troubleshoot/#kernel-compatibility to hopefully get a report of what's missing.